# How can I import javascript file in a file extension *.aspx*?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I am a novice in ASP.NET MVC. Recently, I try to import a javascript file in a asp file.
But I get this Error:

> Not allowed to load local resource

no matter using IE, Chrome or Firefox.

My code:

*/Views/Menu.aspx*

```
  <head runat="server">
  <title>...</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/...(Absolute Path).../jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
```

I study other similar questions and I think maybe this is a secure problem.
But I still don't know how to solve it.

Could anyone give me come give me some advice?

Comment: Sorry. Because I use the very old version(ASP.NET MVC 2), I don't find the way to add .cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are adding your javascript file is wrong:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/...(Absolute Path).../jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just add the required js file in your MVC solution in a folder e.g scripts folder and then drag and drop the file in src of script tag like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have already tried this method,but the broswer will failed to load resource.

Comment: it will be easy to identify the issue of you can share some screenshots indicating issue

Comment: I think maybe the problem is the broswer always open the path *http://localhost/scripts/jquery.min.js*. It is not strange that cannot find this path.